# jquery change handler of object that is replaced

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, triggers, replace

Is there a way to keep checking an object if it's checked after it is replaced

this illustrates the problem I'm having

http://jsfiddle.net/nr6eA/

once the element is replaced the change function is not triggered again, while I have a pretty good idea why this is happening, I'm not sure how to solve this.

I've got a lot of checkboxes, and adding a script to each when they are replaced doesn't seem to be the best idea.

Is there a way of re-initializing the jquery function ofter an ajax update?

Comment: Does your application require the `replaceWith` method or could this be accomplished by changing the id?

Comment: You'd use event delegation. But why are you destroying the elements in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need event delegation. For that purpose you can use `on()` with jQuery 1.7+ like below:

For **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#f').on('change', ' input:checkbox', function() {
        $('#textbox1').val($(this).attr('id') + " " + $(this).is(':checked'));
        $(this).replaceWith('<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="ichange"/>')
    });
});​
```

But, your fiddle shows `jQuery 1.6.2`. In that case you can use `live()` or `delegate()`.

For [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#f input:checkbox').live('change', function() {
        $('#textbox1').val($(this).attr('id') + " " + $(this).is(':checked'));
        $(this).replaceWith('<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="ichange"/>')
    });
});​
```

And for **[`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#f').delegate('input:checkbox', 'change', function() {
        $('#textbox1').val($(this).attr('id') + " " + $(this).is(':checked'));
        $(this).replaceWith('<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="ichange"/>')
    });
});​
```

But it would be better if you can use `.on()` with jQuery 1.7+.